# How do I configure the news server which trn4 uses?

Tags: command-line, configuration, email, hostname, email-client

How do I configure the FQDN from `news.foo.bar` to the actual hostname?

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ trn4
            *** NEWS NEWS ***

Welcome to trn 4.0-test77 (Sep 1, 2010).

Type 'h' at any prompt to get help.  The old (rn-compatible) help
is usually available by typing 'H' as well.

This message will not be displayed again unless it is updated with new
information.

   - The friendly folks at <trn-workers@lists.sourceforge.net>

Connecting to news.foo.bar...Name or service not knownfailed.
Couldn't open any newsrc groups.  Is your access file ok?
thufir@doge:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thufir@doge:~$ trn4
            *** NEWS NEWS ***

Welcome to trn 4.0-test77 (Sep 1, 2010).

Type 'h' at any prompt to get help.  The old (rn-compatible) help
is usually available by typing 'H' as well.

This message will not be displayed again unless it is updated with new
information.

   - The friendly folks at <trn-workers@lists.sourceforge.net>

Connecting to foo.bar.baz...Done.
Unread news in gmane.comp.security.fail2ban.user           54 articles
Unread news in gmane.linux.ubuntu.user                     69 articles
Unread news in gmane.linux.centos.general                  37 articles
Unread news in gmane.comp.gnome.apps.pan.user               7 articles
Unread news in gmane.discuss                                3 articles
etc.

ADD newsgroups       145941 groups

a     0 1stone.archive
b     0 3b.config
d     0 3com.totalservice.test
e     0 3dfx.game.s
f     0 a.a.mis.philadelphia
g     0 a.a.mis.talk
i     0 a2i.b
j     0 a2i.info
l     0 a2i.lists.com-priv
o     0 aaa.product.jsp
r     0 abg.kultur
s     0 abg.test
t     0 acc.sbell.usa-to
u     0 acc.sbell.usa-today.banks
v     0 acc.sbell.ushead.life
w     0 achilles.general
x     0 acid-net.koordination.news
y     0 add
z     0 adfa.journals
1     0 adobe.acrobat.enterprise.installation.solutions
2     0 adobe.acrobat.scripting
3     0 adobe.golive.macintosh
4     0 adobe.golive.webworkgroupserver
5     0 adobe.livecycle.form.manager
6     0 adobe.livemotion.featurerequests
7     0 adobe.photoshop.scripting
8     0 adobe.web.design
9     0 aecom.med2y.pharmacology
0     0 agora.scienza.scienza
B     0 ai.ua
C     0 aist.rips.test
F     0 akmos.contest
G     0 akr.misc
I     0 al.freedom.jbpe
K     0 alabama.birmingham.radio
V     0 alabama.birmingham.students
W     0 alc.alc.c2h5oh

-- Select a newsgroup to add (natural order) -- Top 0% [>Z] --


Newsgroups       11 groups

a    54 gmane.comp.security.fail2ban.user
b    69 gmane.linux.ubuntu.user
d    37 gmane.linux.centos.general
e     7 gmane.comp.gnome.apps.pan.user
f     3 gmane.discuss
g     1 gmane.comp.telephony.pbx.asterisk
i     1 gwene.org.raspberrypi.asterisk
j     1 gmane.comp.telephony.pbx.asterisk.java
l     1 gmane.comp.telephony.pbx.asterisk.call-centers
o    15 gmane.comp.telephony.pbx.asterisk.user
r     9 gmane.mail.alpine.info

-- Select a newsgroup (natural order) -- All [Z>] --
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/news/server 
foo.bar.baz
thufir@doge:~$
```

By editing `/etc/news/server` it seems that trn4 starts correctly.  However, I'm not entirely sure that this the correct setting.  Is it possible to put multiple servers there?  is this file used **only** by `trn4`?  Not sure.